# How to do calculation with multidimensional array in php

Tags: php

I am trying to do calculation with multidimensional array. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$items = array(
    array('id' =>1,
        'DESC' =>'Widget Corporation',
        'Price' =>30.00),
    array(
        'id' =>2,
        'DESC' =>'Website Corporation',
        'Price' =>40.00,
    ),
    array(
        'id' =>3,
        'DESC' =>'Content Management',
        'Price' =>50.00,
    ),
    array(
        'id' =>4,
        'DESC' =>'Registration System',
        'more'=>'Please Buy it',
        'Price' =>60.00
    )
);

foreach($items as $item){
    $total =$item['Price'] + $item['Price'];
    echo $total;
}
```

i am getting this result: 6080100120 instead of getting 180

Comment: You're looping through your array, and each item is having its price added to itself; then you echo out the result (with no trailing line break). What are you trying to produce?

Comment: Do you even understand what the `foreach()` loop is doing?

Answer (score 3):

```
$total = 0;
foreach($items as $item){
    $total += $item['Price'];
}
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting is "60 80 100 120". The price of each item doubled, all rolled together, since you don't have any way to separate it.  Change your code to this:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($items as $item){
    $total += $item['Price'];
    echo "$total<br />\n";
}
echo "$total<br />\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$items = array(
    array('id' =>1,
        'DESC' =>'Widget Corporation',
        'Price' =>30.00),
    array(
        'id' =>2,
        'DESC' =>'Website Corporation',
        'Price' =>40.00,
    ),
    array(
        'id' =>3,
        'DESC' =>'Content Management',
        'Price' =>50.00,
    ),
    array(
        'id' =>4,
        'DESC' =>'Registration System',
        'more'=>'Please Buy it',
        'Price' =>60.00
    )
);

foreach($items as $item){
    $total+=$item['Price'] ;

}
echo $total;
```

replace with this code

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = 0;

foreach ( $items as $item )
    $total += $item['Price'];

echo $total;
```

Comment: It's bad practice to leave out the `{}` around the `foreach` body.

Comment: I tend to ignore (responsibly) this recommendation when I realize that braces are making my code visually polluted. I just put then when the repeated statement is too long or there is a multiple statement block.

Comment: @tassoevan It's bad to propose bad practices, despite our personal taste

Comment: Bad and good pratices are agreements between community members and development teams. All my coworkers follow this.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $total=0; 
 foreach($items as $item){
     $total =$total + $item['Price'] ;    
 }
 echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

I you want just the sum of the prices, try

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($items as $item){
 $total += $item['Price'];   
}    
echo $total;
```